# display & hide a div without CSS, jquery or javascript

Tags: html

I've got a tough one. I work for a company that uses a sharepoint that is 100% text based due to varying network performace issues accross the world. It provides the option to input HTML for styling but scrubs any javascript. I do not have access to code CSS and I'm assuming jquery is not available.

I would like to embed images into the sharepoint as a proof of concept by taking advantage of a floating div (or iframe) that displays with an href to display a png file stored on a server. I don't want the div (or the image) to load unless the user clicks a link or a button.

I'm pretty amature at anything other than basic HTML formating. I'm not even sure it's possible to do something like this with only html.

Thank you in advance to anyone willing to take a stab at this.

Comment: It is **impossible** to do this in pure HTML.

Comment: You can do it with *just* CSS, or with *just* JS.  But not without either.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it wants to find a solution to a problem while avoiding all the possible means of achieving that solution.

Comment: Can you use `style` attribute in the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with this HTML, which is ugly and unmaintainable.

1. Use an `iframe` with `scrolling="none"`. Use `width` and `height` attributes to give it dimensions.
2. Inside the `iframe` have your `img` elements with an `id` attribute. Ensure they're spaced with enough vertical space so they can't be *seen* by default, and appear isolated when viewed later.
3. Link your links to those `id` attributes, e.g. `<a href="#image" target="your-frame">link</a>`

Comment: Thank you very much for this. If I can just proof it to IT, it might convince them to loosen up their restriction on a more viable solution. I'll give it a go today! I'll post my results so that other may benefit.